# Проблема с наследованием в Qt (ошибка компиляции)

Tags: qt, наследование, ui

Всем доброго времени суток!
С Qt новичок, что-то туплю.
Итак есть объявление класса:

```
#include <QLabel>
#include <QDialog>
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include "pipeline.h"

namespace Ui 
{
  class Draw;
}

class Draw : public QDialog
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  int MaxCounter;
  QLabel *Label;
  GstBuffer *Buffer;

private:
  Ui::Draw *ui;
  Pipeline *pPipe;
  int VidCounter;

public:
  Draw(Pipeline *, QWidget *parent = 0);
  int DrawBuffer(void);

private:
};
```

Реализация:

```
#include "draw.h"

Draw::Draw(Pipeline *p, QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent), ui(new Ui::Draw)
{
  pPipe = p;
  VidCounter = 0;

  QLabel mode;
  mode.setPixmap(QPixmap(QString::fromUtf8(":/icons/mode1.png")));
  mode.setGeometry(QRect(42, 40, 49, 69));
  mode.show();

  while(1);
}
```

Однако при попытке компиляции выдает 2 ошибки: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct Ui::Draw' и error: forward declaration of 'struct Ui::Draw'.

Как с этим разобраться ума не приложу.. Если убираю наследование, то QLabel не отображается на экране, виден только курсор в центре экрана.

Благодарю за любую помощь и мысли!

**P.S. Исправил. Однако возникла другая проблема с компиляцией.**
Определение:

```
namespace Ui 
{
    class Draw;
}

class Ui::Draw : public QDialog
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  int MaxCounter;
  QLabel *Label;
  GstBuffer *Buffer;

private:
  Ui::Draw *ui;
  Pipeline *pPipe;
  int VidCounter;

public:
  Draw(Pipeline *, QWidget *parent = 0);
  int DrawBuffer(void);

private:
};
```

Реализация:

```
Ui::Draw::Draw(Pipeline *p, QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent), ui(new Ui::Draw)
{
  pPipe = p;
  VidCounter = 0;

  QLabel mode;
  mode.setPixmap(QPixmap(QString::fromUtf8(":/icons/mode1.png")));
  mode.setGeometry(QRect(42, 40, 49, 69));
  mode.show();

  while(1);
}
```

Но теперь не компилируется со следующими ошибками:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'Ui::Draw::Draw()'
candidates are: Ui::Draw::Draw(Pipeline*, QWidget*)
note:                 Ui::Draw::Draw(const Ui::Draw&)
```

Что-то я в ступоре.. не понимаю чего ему не так?

Comment: а где реализация `int DrawBuffer(void);` (кстати, зачем там, можно и без void)

Comment: Я посчитал, что DrawBuffer() не относится к данной проблеме, поэтому не стал его приводить... Насчет void привычка от Си осталась.

Comment: просто ошибка намекает на то, что не все функции класса были реализованы (или случайно забыли их реализовать). Если сорцы покажете (полные), то скорее всего причину можно будет найти.

Comment: Да нет, реализовать не забыл:
int Draw::DrawBuffer()
{
   return 0;
}

Comment: У Вас ***два разных*** класса: `Ui::Draw` и `::Draw`.

Comment: Ох, спасибо за внимательность. Исправил. Правда возникла другая проблема с компиляцией.

Comment: У Вас там вообще какая-то чертовщина. Вы создаёте `Ui::Draw` и в его конструкторе вызываете `new Ui::Draw`. Зачем? И в конструкции `ui(new Ui::Draw)` вы вызываете конструктор без параметров, которого в классе не существует, что Вам и пытается сказать компилятор.

Comment: Добавьте `#include "ui_draw.h"` в `.cpp`. Этот файл в процессе сборки создаёт вспомогательная утилита `uic` из вашего `draw.ui`

Answer (score 1):

В общем разобрался. Проблема заключалась в том, что дал одинаковые названия форме: Draw и своему классу: тоже Draw. В исходном коде изменил название формы на WDraw, в draw.h подключил #include "ui_WDraw.h" и все заработало.

Всем спасибо за помощь и подсказки!

Answer (score 1):

> `QLabel` не отображается на экране

и правильно делает.

Здесь вы создаёте объект `QLabel` на стеке, и поэтому по окончании работы конструктора он разрушается:

```
Ui::Draw::Draw(Pipeline *p, QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent), ui(new Ui::Draw)
{
  pPipe = p;
  VidCounter = 0;

  QLabel mode;
  mode.setPixmap(QPixmap(QString::fromUtf8(":/icons/mode1.png")));
  mode.setGeometry(QRect(42, 40, 49, 69));
  mode.show();

  while(1);
}
```

Правильно будет написать так:

```
QLabel* mode = new QLabel(this);
...
mode->show();
```

И кстати, зачем нужна последняя строка конструктора `while(1);`?